# Setting Up Google Analytics SDK4 Android with XML config file

Tags: android, xml, google-analytics

I'm having a bit of trouble getting Analytics SDK4 running. I want Analytics to catch all uncaught exceptions, and therefore I have to do the following according to the docs:

"To automatically send all uncaught exceptions in your app using the ga_reportUncaughtExceptions value, add this line to your XML configuration file:"

```
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
```

I haven't used a XML config file for analytics before, and the info about it is sparse, to say the least. To start out I just want one tracker, the app I'm working on is not using E-commerce, and since it's the only app using Analytics right now, I won't need a Global tracker, right?

So, according to the docs:

"if you have a global tracker you could create a file called global_tracker.xml in your project's res/xml directory and add the following resources:"

I don't, I just need an app_tracker atm, so I created app_tracker.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>
    <screenName name="com.blabla.project">Main ScreenView</screenName>
    <string name="ga_trackingId">XXXXXXXX</string>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Now, the way I got a ref to a tracker before, is by using the line

```
  tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).newTracker("XX-XXXXXX-X");
```

Other examples on how to get a ref to a tracker I found in the docs are:

```
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
        TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

or

```
Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
      : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
          : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
```

The last one being part of a multi-tracker setup, which I don't use, and the first one not working (why would I need to cast to AnalyticsSampleApp?), getApplication()).getTracker can't be resolved..

So, my questions: Am I taking the correct approach in only wanting the one tracker to start out with? And how would I get a ref to said tracker. Is the tracker automatically created because of the XML config file and do I get a ref to it somehow, or do I have to instantiate a new one, and if so, how would I use the key that's in the config file, and not putting it in manually? I can't even get a R.string.ga_trackingId ref, why is that? Some examples I saw say I also need to use

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource" android:resource="@xml/app_tracker" />
```

in the application element of my manifest. The docs don't mention anything about the manifest though..

Why couldn't they have just left it as simple as with Easy tracker? :D Any help would be Much appreciated! I can't see the proverbial tree through the woods, so to speak.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to use APP_TRACKER,

then use this method:

```
  synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

      GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(LogLevel.VERBOSE);
      Tracker t = null;
      if(trackerId==TrackerName.APP_TRACKER){
          t= analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
      }
      mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

    }
    ////
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
  }
```

Property_id is the id which you got after setting google analytics property from here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042508

Answer (score 0):

Use what @Richa wrote but instead of creating Tracker from string resource (PROPERTY_ID) that configures nothing, do that to inflate xml configuration file:

```
Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.default_tracker)
```

You have to define your analytics id either way in xml as it authenticates you in analytics account.

For further information see complete example of basic configuration: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/